# NestJs Build option to create single file

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I am having to NestJS app on running `npm run build` one app creates one single file and the other app create as many .js files as I have in in may app

I am unable to find the settings where I can say I need one single file. Any NestJS Developer who can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably from `nest build` being ran inside a monorepo and Nest using `webpack` to bundle the source code together. In a non-monorepo project, `nest build` uses `tsc`, Typescript's compiler, to transpile the ts files to js which outputs each file individually rather than bundling them together. [You can read more about Nest's CLI and building options here](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo)